# Leaflet Route In multiple lat long

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox

i'm expected **output picture** attached to him by **sample google map**.

given the following my **leaflet map script**. but cannot enable to achieve i will expected output.

[image]
function single_vehicle_route(data){

```
            var latlng_val =[];

            var defaultCoords = [11.016844,76.955832];
                var StartMarker = {};
                var EndMarker = {};
                //set up our map
                var map = L.map('single_map').setView(defaultCoords,6);
                L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                    {
                    maxZoom: 16
                    }).addTo(map);

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 


                var latlngs = [[data[i].lat,data[i].lng]];

                            var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);

                            map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());

            }
            //console.log(latlng_val);  


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Build up your list of latlngs and then add the polyline. In your code you're repeatedly adding a polyline of one point.

For example:

```
var latlngs = [];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   latlngs.push([data[i].lat, data[i].lng]);
}

var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
```

edit: To add markers at the beginning/end

```
L.marker(latlngs[0]).addTo(map);
L.marker(latlngs[latlngs.length-1]).addTo(map);
```

For more information on custom markers, checkout the [Leaflet documentation.](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#marker-option)

Answer (score 0):

Polylines always draw the straight lines. So you didn't get the exact path. My suggestion is to use polyline.antPath instead of polyline